# The density of conditional distribution.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, conditional-probability

Let $X$ and $Y$ be independent random variables, both of exponential distibution, such that $EX=\frac{1}{2},EY=1$. Calculate the density of conditional distribution $f_{X+Y|X}(z|x)$. In fact I am interested in $s=3$.

My idea: I know that I should apply the formula $f_{Z|X}(z,x)=\frac{f_{Z,X}(z,x)}{f_X(x)}$. However I do not know how to obtain $f_{Z,X}(z,x)$. Could you please help?

Answer (score 3):

Hint:  Given that $X = x$, the conditional distribution of $Y$ is the same as the unconditional distribution of $Y$ because $X$ and $Y$ are given to be independent
random variables, and so knowing the value of $X$ tells us nothing that we did
not already know about $Y$.  Thus, the conditional distribution of $X+Y$, *given* that $X$ has taken on the value $x$ is the same as the unconditional distribution of $x+Y$. Can you work this out? Remember that $x$ is just a constant. Replace $x$
by $3$ if you need to.

Answer (score 2):

Let $Z = X+Y \mid X=x$. The complementary cumulative distribution function of $Z$ is easy to work out:
$$
S_Z(z) = \Pr(Z > z) = \Pr\left(X+Y > z \mid X=x\right) =
    \Pr\left(Y > z-x \mid X=x\right) = \Pr\left(Y > z-x \right)
$$
Hence
$$
   S_Z(z) = \begin{cases} \mathrm{e}^{-(z-x)} & z \geqslant x \cr 0 & z <x  \end{cases}
$$
The probability density function then is obtained by differentiation:
$$
   f_{X+Y\mid X}\left(z\mid x\right) = -S_Z^\prime(z) = \begin{cases} \mathrm{e}^{-(z-x)} & z \geqslant x \cr 0 & z < x  \end{cases}
$$